# Set Order status to "Pending" By default when no option is selected

Tags: magento

I have created a new payment method. There is an option to select "New order status" which has only one option i.e. "pending". When this option is not set to any value, new order status becomes "processing".

But I have observed in "Check / Money Order" method that, When no option is set, new order status becomes "pending".

Can anyone suggest which one is correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default new order status is "Processing" set by magento. If you select any specific status for that payment method then that status will set.

In "Check / Money Order" method, payment has not been authorized, that's why magento set its status Pending.

Hope will help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to the above issue.

Magento has a default authorize function which sets the state as processing.

You will have to edit/override the below file: code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php

```
protected function _authorize($isOnline, $amount){

$amount = $this->_formatAmount($amount, true);
$this->setBaseAmountAuthorized($amount);

// do authorization
$order  = $this->getOrder();
$state  = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$status = true;
```

Change the state to new or whatever you want to set when authorizing any payment from payment gateway.